# Burninate [internet-download-manager]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

It has a grand total of [5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-download-manager), most of which are bad; its wiki entry [reads like an advertisement](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/internet-download-manager/info); and it just isn't related to programming, hence off-topic for SO.

Comment: Looks like it's already [meta-tag:status-completed]...

Comment: And whack the user that created/approved it!

Comment: [jdownloader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdownloader?sort=newest) is very similar... Burninate it too ?