# Burninate [jdownloader]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The tag [jdownloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdownloader) is very similar to [one recently burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290739/burninate-internet-download-manager) - very few questions, the Info page reads out like an advertisement, etc.

An user advised to burninate it in the comments of the linked thread, and I agree that the tag :

**is unambiguous**.

**is not-on-topic** : most questions refer to Java development linked to JDownloader, but the downloader is not the topic in question.

**Does not add anything meaningful** and **differs in meaning from one question to another** : We have questions about developping an app for JDownloader, some asking how a website can see if it is running, etc.

I believe this tag should be burninated - especially since the question count is so low. I can edit them out if needed.

Comment: I **disagree** with this tag burnination request. If the question is about developing plugin for JDownloader, it is on topic. Feel free to close questions which are off-topic, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh Of the 9 questions, only one or two are about developing a plugin for JDownloader. Should I remove the tag on the others and leave as-is the 2 questions?

Comment: I have remove tag from 3 questions which does not have anything with JDownloader. The rest should be reviewed according to the site scope. From what I see, these 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620536/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281684/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346510/ are valid programming question. These 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527950/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678261/ asks about technology used in JDownloader - I'm not sure whether they are on-topic or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500624/ should be closed.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Please post some recap as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with this tag burnination request, since question about developing plugin for JDownloader should be on-topic.

I have removed the tags from these 3 questions, which don't seem to have anything to do with JDownloader:

- [How to change the link in jdownloads in Joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482491/how-to-change-the-link-in-jdownloads-in-joomla) (about jDownloads plugin in Joomla)
- [Java Downloading Flood Prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905982/java-downloading-flood-prevention) (pure Java question?)
- [Download File Crash Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044198/download-file-crash-android) (no evidence that it is related to JDownloader)

These questions are related to JDownloader plugin/feature development:

- [JDownloader, check link, add link, read captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620536/jdownloader-check-link-add-link-read-captcha)
- [How to generate a DLC file for JDownloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281684/how-to-generate-a-dlc-file-for-jdownloader)
- [JDownloader Remote how to detect ip adress Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346510/jdownloader-remote-how-to-detect-ip-adress-android) (not too sure about this one, though)

These questions ask about technology used in JDownloader, which I'm not sure if they are on-topic or not (go ahead and cast close vote if they are really off-topic):

- [How can a website check if a application is running on my pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527950/how-can-a-website-check-if-a-application-is-running-on-my-pc)
- [What installer solution does the JDownloader project uses to create it's installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678261/what-installer-solution-does-the-jdownloader-project-uses-to-create-its-install)

This question looks off-topic/unclear:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500624/os-x-and-java-memory-usage